# PostgreSQL Streaming Replication - invalid connection option "sslsni"

Tags: postgresql, ssl, streaming, replication, sni

I want to setup primary and replica on the same server. My server is CentOS 9. primary and replica servers ports are 5433 and 5434. I create replica server using pg_basebackup command as follows:

`pg_basebackup -h localhost -U repuser --checkpoint=fast -D /tmp/replica_db/ -R --slot=some_name -C --port=5433`

Now when starting replica server I get following error and the primary server could not connect to replica server:

`could not connect to the primary server: invalid connection option "sslsni"`

What should I do to make primary connect to replica server?

Comment: What are the version of the PostgreSQL database and the pg_basebackup binary?

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.7

Comment: And what about the pg_basebackup binary?

Comment: Both of them are version 13.7. I didn't install any version other than PostgreSQL 13.7. I found the solution. I edited the postgresql.auto.conf file and deleted the sslsni parameter. I realized that sslsni is a new parameter provided in the PostgreSQL 14, but I don't know why pg_basebackup in version 13.7 set this parameter in the auto.conf file.

Comment: The string 'sslsni' doesn't appear in 13 source, so i don't see how this could happen.  I suspect you have some kind of bastardized installation floating around.  You could just remove that connection option, but I would worry you are just setting yourself up for more trouble ahead of you do that rather than solving the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I check the sources but I couldn't find sslsni parameter. I'm in test environment. I will check whole the installation process soon. I hope to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

because you use the upper version  pg_basebackup binary,and your server version is lower than this pg_basebackup